# JQuery 'OR' operator to combine two variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get help in my JQuery function. I'm very new with `JS` - `JQuery` - `AJAX` and I would like to make my function easier.

Up to now, each function are located in specific HTML file. But I want to set both to `app.js` file and factorize to an unique function.

I have this :

```
$("#id_releasing_body").change(function () {
  var url = $("#form_search").attr("data-provider-url");
  var releasingBodyId = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      'releasing_body': releasingBodyId
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $("#id_member_state").val(data.member_state);
    }
  });

});
```

and this :

```
$("#id_release_body_institution").change(function () {
  var url = $("#form_search").attr("data-provider-url");
  var releasingBodyId = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      'releasing_body': releasingBodyId
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $("#id_member_state").val(data.member_state);
    }
  });

});
```

As you can see, it's the same thing, just the `change` variable at the beginning is different. My question is : Is it possible to factorize both functions in one.

This is what I've done, but it doesn't work (maybe the idea is correct) :

```
if ($("#id_releasing_body")||$("#id_release_body_institution")).change(function () {
  var url = $("#form_search").attr("data-provider-url");
  var releasingBodyId = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      'releasing_body': releasingBodyId
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $("#id_member_state").val(data.member_state);
    }
  });

});
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you intend on using a lot of Ajax calls, you might as well create a function for it so that your code will be more readable, other than that, your code looks fine with given answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try by comma separator or [multiple-selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$("#id_releasing_body ,#id_release_body_institution") .../ rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse the function here, name it, and pass the named function in instead of an anonymous function. Then your or logic can work in an if or switch case. It's not totally clear to me what you're checking for here i.e. if there is an id_releasing_body does that exclude the possibility of having an id_release_body_institution?